# If $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f''(x)=\infty$ it is always the case that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My teacher proposed the following question in our class:

> Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that
>   $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f''(x)=\infty$. Find the value of $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$ or show that it doesn't exist.

I found that both $f(x)=-\ln(x)$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}x$ satisfy the conditions and make the proposed limit equal to $0$. How do I prove that this is always the case? Thanks.

Comment: What about $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$? We have $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $f''(x) =  \frac{1}{4x^{3/2}}$. Thus $f$ satisfies the conditions. However $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}2x = 0.$$

Comment: If $f(x)=1/x$, then $f(x)/f'(x)=-x$, tending to 0 as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: The limit for $f(x)=-\ln x$ is also zero.

Comment: I checked my limits and edited the post. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_0>0$ with $f'<0,f''>0 $ on $(0,x_0).$ We have

$$\tag 1\left | \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right| \le \left | \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{f'(x)}\right | + \left |\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x)}\right|.$$

The second summand on the right tends to $0$ as $x\to 0^+.$  It follows that

$$\tag 2 \limsup_{x\to 0^+}\left |\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right| \le \limsup_{x\to 0^+}\left | \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{f'(x)}\right |.$$

By the mean value theorem, the fraction on the right side of $(2)$ equals

$$\tag 3 \frac{|f'(c_x)||x-x_0|}{|f'(x)|}.$$

Now $f''>0$ on $(0,x_0)$ implies $f'$ increases there. Thus $(3)$ is bounded above by

$$\le \frac{|f'(x)||x-x_0|}{|f'(x)|} = |x-x_0| < x_0.$$

It follows that the left side of $(2)$ is $\le x_0.$ Since $x_0$ is arbitrarily small, the the left side of $(2)$ is $0.$ This proves $f(x)/f'(x) \to 0$ as desired.

NOTE (added later): I did not use $f''\to \infty,$ only that $f''>0$ near $0.$

Comment: Instead of using the limsup, can't you just use the same argument with the usual limit?

Comment: I use the limsup because we don't know any limits exist at the beginning; the limsup always exists.

Comment: Is the following also correct? Let $\epsilon>0$, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =0$ and $x_n>0$ for all $n$. Let $x_0$ be chosen as above with the extra condition that $x_0< \epsilon/2$. We now know there is $N$ such that $|\frac{f(x_0)}{f(x_n)}|<\epsilon/2$ if $n>N$.  Now by a similar argument as yours above we find $$|\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}|< \epsilon|$$ if $n>N$. I never know whether I made a mistake concerning the fact that $x_0$ depends on $\epsilon$ etc...